# Clicking "Visited X days, X consecutive" errors out

Tags: bug

When clicking on "Visited 267 days, 10 consecutive" on my profile it loads infinitely and in the console it gives this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $cal.datepicker is not a function`

When I open the button again it doesn't have a loading bar anymore, it's just an empty box.
[image: Empty datepicker]

I use Firefox 117